# I'm trying to add numbers from a list at the end of a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add numbers from a list at the end of a linked list using a tail poninter, but I don't understand why my tail is never changing.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head , *tail;

typedef struct node NOD;
//I addd the first node
void addfirst(int num)
{
    NOD *temp;//This is the new node
    temp = (NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = tail = temp;
}
//I add at the end of the list
void add(int num)
{
    NOD *temp;
    temp = (NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

int main()
{
   int n , num, i;
   freopen("intrare.txt" , "r" , stdin);
   scanf("%d" , &n);
   for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
   {
       scanf("%d" , &num);
       if(i==1)
           addfirst(num);
       else
           add(num);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(i==1)` --> `if(i==0)`

Comment: this looks like a answer

Answer (score 0):

```
temp->data = num;
temp->next = NULL;
head = tail = temp;
```

change this code to

```
temp->data = num;
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
```

There is no need to change the tail when you're adding at head. Also by doing `head = tail = temp;` you're losing your previously made list.

Comment: it's the same thing because the "addfirst" function is used only for adding the first node. It's even worst beacuse if I do that the tail will always be equal to NULL.